# Android :: Settings Layout

Tags: android, android-xml

I need help... I got errors with my android xml... Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:key="music"
    android:title="Music"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:summary="Play Music for each screen"
    android:defaultValue="true" />

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="hints"
    android:title="Hints" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:summary="Enable hints during gameplay"
    android:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the error messages:

```
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
You must supply a layout_width attribute.
You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: where is this code??? com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView

Comment: "com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup" is an error message.i got problem with my xml code..

Comment: @user1271277 :post your MockView layout

Comment: @user1271277 : this is preference activity

Comment: Im still new in android. What do you mean by MockView layout?

Comment: @user1271277 : welcome friend.just remove `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` from `CheckBoxPreference`

Comment: i already remove android:layout_height and android:layout_width from CheckBoxPreference and it still result the same..

Comment: @user1271277 :see my answer and try it and give response quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="CheckBoxPreference">

        <CheckBoxPreference
             android:key="music"
             android:title="Music"
             android:summary="Play Music for each screen"
             android:defaultValue="true" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
             android:key="hints"
             android:title="Hints" 
             android:summary="Enable hints during gameplay"
             android:defaultValue="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory> 
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: @user1271277 : maybe try to build or clean and restart Eclipse again

Comment: @user1271277 : your app running on LG Optimus P500 android 2.3 perfectly.just i wanna to conform u have added all drawables or raw mp3 in your project?

Comment: @user1271277 : and where is `com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView` this package in your app?

Comment: sorry i didn't attach with drawables cause the files size is big..if i send all, i think will take hours to wait=.=i dont think u will wait for me too long..my internet is so slow..

Comment: actually i dont really understand what mockview is?sorry..as im said,im still new in android and in process of learning..

Comment: @user1271277 : and second question?

Comment: in my Game.java..how can i add more words for each category?

Comment: @user1271277 : sorry firend i do't known how.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your layout xml files you may have forgot to add `layout_width` to a view. this attribute is required for any view in an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_test"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.marlonlu.pinterest.ui.module.GallaryView
            android:id="@+id/gridview_test"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

From above code, you can see how to define my custom view **com.marlonlu.pinterest.ui.module.GallaryView** , In Android you must define **layout_width** and **layout_height** in your layout which use custom view.