# Android::menu cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings1, menu);
return true;
}
```

I need help. i got error at "R.menu" which the error message "menu cannot be resolved or is not a field"..Thanks

Comment: Did you clean your project after adding your menu layout ?

Comment: yes.i already did that but still got error.. my layout also got problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044898/android-settings-layout

Answer (score 1):

If there is error in your layout the R file is not generated so it is normal to get this error.

You need to correct the errors in your layout first, then cleaning, and R will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks.. but i still stuck at my layout.. i cant figure out what is the problem..

Answer (score 0):

you are using Preference xml as an menu reference that's why reciving this error so make a menu.xml or add as:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

and you can add dynamically as:

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + 1, 5, "??").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + 2, 2, "??").setIcon(
                    android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
            return true; 
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case Menu.FIRST + 1:
               startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SettingActivity.class));
                break;
            case Menu.FIRST + 2:
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Menu Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `imports`. If you imported some kind of `.R` file from some other project (maybe a library project) like `import com.someotherpackage.R;` you need to delete that line, then clean your project.

Right now it's probably referencing the wrong `.R` file, or you have a typo in a name somewhere.